# Qt Linux Mint 19.2 QSslSocket

Tags: qt, linux-mint, smtpclient, qsslsocket

I developed small Qt App for sending mails over smtp 465 port. It works on my developer linux mint 19.2 machine. When I deploy the app with all the libs to Mint 17.3 machine I get QAbstractSocketError::HostNotFoundError. I am using QSslSocket.

If I deploy my app and libs to another linux mint 19.2 machine it work without any problems. So the problem is the difference in mint 19.2 and 17.3. I exhausted all my possibilities/ideas.

p.s.

The OpenSsl is the same installed on both machines!

Comment: Which Qt version are you using, and which OpenSSL version is it loading? Are you sure it's the right one? Is there any output before the error occurs, eg about unresolved functions?

Comment: Qt 5.13. Ldd shows all lib dependancies are ok. App runs without any problems. No error prior I use my smtp function inside my app. After I run part of my app to send mail  debug shows: stateChanged  QAbstractSocket::HostLookupState
stateChanged  QAbstractSocket::UnconnectedState
error  QAbstractSocket::HostNotFoundError On the same machine thunderbird sends and receives mails with the same mail settings without problems. Both machines have OpenSsl 1.1.1b installed.

Comment: QSslSocket::sslLibraryBuildVersionString() shows 1.1.1b OpenSsl version- the same as installed on deploying machine.